# Shared node_modules across multiple projects

Tags: node.js, angular6, node-modules

Node.js Version- v8.12.0
Windows 10.

Hi Team.
I have 5 individual angular-v6 projects. Each application having its own Node_modules, Which is used for development purpose.

I am using JBoss as a application server and maven as a build tool. At the time build it create Node_Modules folder for each application. The problem is the size of node_module is too much, which takes too much space and time to build the application.

Is there any way by which we can share one node_module across all 5 application?

Comment: You might want to try placing all 5 applications under 1 main directory that has the main `node_modules` directory

Comment: Thanks for the response,  But i can not go for this option. Please do let me know if there are any other option.